# Office Click-to-Run side-by-side with local installation

Tags: microsoft-visio, office365

I have looked for an official support position on this and not having any luck. I have a machine with Office 2013 Click-to-Run installed as part of the Office 365 Home Premium offering. This offering does not include Visio.

I have a separate Visio 2013 retail license for a local installation. I would like to use that on the same machine as the Office 2013 Click-to-Run installation.

In the past, I have had issues doing this with a CTR copy of Outlook with a local install of Lync, but that's a special combination given the Lync-Outlook integration so I don't think I can apply that experience here.

This is different than the case of preview vs. release as both products are not preview versions (there's another question that relates to the Visio/Office 365 combination but it explicitly relates to that combination after starting with Preview, so it doesn't directly apply here.)

I know Visio is available as an Office 365 licensed product with CTR but that would mean paying for another copy of Visio, if that offering is even available in combination with the Home Premium O365 SKU.

What I'm looking for is someone who has done this kind of setup - O365 without Visio and local Visio - confirming it works, giving hints, explaining any support issues, etc.

Comment: You should have no problem installing Viso with your Office installation.  Since the Preview versions are not supported by Microsoft at this point I suggest just using the retail versions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you believe this is the answer (without the "Preview" bit since Preview is not involved in any way, as stated) please make it an answer. (Note: I really would like someone who has done this for real and can say it does work completely.)

Comment: What makes you think I have not done it? I won't be posting an answer for this question.

Comment: I can't give you credit for an answer if it's not posted as an answer. I don't know if you have done it or not, you didn't say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was work to be done, so the install was tried. The activation of local Visio broke the activation of CTR Office, but it was easily solved reactivating it when prompted. Running local Visio after that did a repair, which AGAIN broke the CTR activation. After reactivating the CTR again, everything seems to be stable, and the Outlook Visio previewer (from the viewer) seems to be working, but I don't know if that is coming from the CTR package installing the viewer or the local install of the viewer. In other words, I don't know how well shared components are coping. At the moment, for basic Visio use, everything's fine, so that's good enough for now. If any other issues come up I will edit the answer.

Comment: This matches my experience.